# read hidden file

Tags: c#, javascript, hidden-files

Is it possible to read file with attribute `hidden` in program? I know the path to file.

For example, if I copy a file to some place and set the attribute hidden:

```
File.Copy("sender.exe", path+"system.exe");
File.SetAttributes(path + "sender.exe", FileAttributes.Hidden);
```

Can I run the hidden .EXE file with this code (if I know path)?

```
function Run(path, lang, city) {
    var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
    shell.run(path + " " + city + " " + lang);
}
```

Comment: what about trying your code ?

Comment: If you already have the code, why don't you just try it?

Comment: Why are you copying sender.exe to system.exe and hiding it?  and then trying to run it?  that seems fishy.

Answer (score 5):

Yes; that's perfectly possible.

Comment: +1, "The file or directory is hidden. *It is not included in an ordinary directory listing.*"